# using Axios to post uploaded image results in empty file collection

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, axios

```
   const fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', this.state.selectedFile, this.state.selectedFile.name);
    const postData = {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        body: fd
    }

    //this correctly shows the image object and name:
    console.log('selected image file name: ', this.state.selectedFile.name);
    console.log('select image: ', this.state.selectedFile);

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `/api/gameStats/profileImage/${this.props.profileId}/files/upload`,
        postData
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log('then: ', response);
    })
    .catch(function (response) {
        console.log('catch: ', response);
    });


   [HttpPost("upload")]
    public virtual async Task<IActionResult> PostMulti(Int64 parentId, ICollection<IFormFile> fileData)
    {
        'fileData is always empty... :(

        TParent parent;

        using (var tran = Session.BeginTransaction()) {
            parent = Repository.GetParent(parentId);
            if (!Security.CanCreate(CurrentUser, parent, null))
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
            tran.Rollback();
        }

        foreach (var file in fileData) {
            await SaveFile(file, parent);
        }

        return Created("", Map(Repository.Get(parentId)));
    }
```

Comment: should be `axios({data: postData})` instead of `axios({postData})`. And secondly why do you put `method`, `credentials` and `body` props as the request body of the `axios` request?

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan postData is an object I create above, does it still need to prefaced with 'data:'?  'method' and 'body' are expected by the API I am hitting. Thanks!

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass required `data` field in your axios request object
as outlined [here](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)

> // `data` is the data to be sent as the request body
>     // Only applicable for request methods 'PUT', 'POST', and 'PATCH'
>     // When no `transformRequest` is set, must be of one of the following types:
>     // - string, plain object, ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, URLSearchParams
>     // - Browser only: FormData, File, Blob
>     // - Node only: Stream, Buffer
>     data: {
>       firstName: 'Fred'
>     },

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: `/api/gameStats/profileImage/${this.props.profileId}/files/upload`,
        data: postData
    })
```

P. S. you don't need to pass file name, when appending to `FormData`, since it's derived from it automatically if it is of type `File` as outlined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append).

> The filename reported to the server (a USVString), when a Blob or File is passed as the second parameter. The default filename for Blob objects is "blob". The default filename for File objects is the file's filename.

```
fd.append('image', this.state.selectedFile);
```